# Reference to class procedure

Tags: arrays, delphi, types, delphi-xe7

I'm have such static class procedure in my record:

```
TRec = record
  class procedure Proc; stdcall; static;
end;
```

Now I need array of such class procedures in my record:

```
TRec2 = record
  Procs: array of TClassProcStdcallStatic;
end;
```

This is possible and how to determine TClassProcStdcallStatic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define it like this:

```
type
  TClassProcStdcallStatic = procedure; stdcall;
```

The `static` keyword means that the method has no `Self` pointer and is a single pointer function type. As opposed to `of object` double pointer function types.

Comment: and this is will be class static procedure?

Comment: Yes, this type will serve your needs

Comment: Ah, they finally fixed that. In D2007 you still had to cast. (And declare `TRec` to be an `object` instead of `record` to avoid an internal compiler error.)

Comment: Would declaring `TClassProcStdcallStatic = reference to procedure stdcall;` come with any disadvantages? This way, you'd also be able to assign anonymous methods to a variable of `TClassProcStdcallStatic`.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful That would work. I tend to avoid that approach if possible because the perf isn't as good. But perf may not be your issue.